# AAD - Owner password credential flow

Tags: azure-active-directory

Hi I am trying to use owner password credential flow by giving username and password and it is giving below error. I am using the native application as the client Id.

```
 UserPasswordCredential credentials = new UserPasswordCredential(_userName, _password);
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(_authority);
    var accessToken = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(_apiResourceId, _clientId, credentials);
    accessToken.AccessToken;
```

> AdalServiceException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'xxxxxxxx' named 'nativeclient'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource

I have a scenario where I cannot use client credential flow. Is there anything I am missing as when I use the powershell client ID `1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2` it works. How can I consent this application on the context of user as I am not the tenant admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the permissions you have added require admin-consent.

You can see it on Azure portal:
[image: permissions]

If the permissions require admin-consent, you have to use an admin account to do the consent by clicking "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}" here:
[image]

If the permissions don't require admin-consent, you just need to use a non-admin account to do the consent by accessing https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant}/oauth2/authorize?client_id={Client ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={Reply URL}&resource={Resource you want to access, for example: https://graph.microsoft.com/}&prompt=consent.
[image: user-consent]

Besides, could you please provide more details the "scenario where I cannot use client credential flow"?

Comment: I want to manage certain application https://graph.windows.net/xxxx/applications. Say I want to add an additional secret. I am not a tenant admin. However, If I give owner access to few application which I own to a service account I can still manage with password flow. If I ask for application access it will be applicable for all applications in the tenant, which will be much riskier most of the applications I don't own. Tenant admin's will never give me that access.